# How do I select an XML tag or class in a Javascript event and update its CSS style properties and classList?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to develop a mini program for WeChat (a large Chinese messaging and social media service). The only accepted languages are XML, CSS, JSON, and Javascript. I know that XML does not have access to the HTML DOM methods that I normally use for updating styles and classLists in response to event listeners. Is there an XML equivalent for querySelector and querySelectorAll I can use to target tags/elements and change styles in response to events? And is bindtap as equivalent to addEventListener as I can get in XML? Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

If the `DOMParser` is not available in the miniprogram, maybe txml, an extreamly small pure js xml parser is an option for you.
I know the size for miniapps is very much limited in wechat miniapps.  ~2MB?

Adding [txml](http://npmjs.com/package/txml) will only set you back about 4kb.

https://unpkg.com/txml@4.0.0/tXml.min.js

** I am the author of txml ** and also developed the parser for such limited environments.